# Excel still in compatability mode after Save As xlsm

Tags: excel, vb6

My code opens a .xls file in Excel. If it is excel 2007 or later this opens in compatability mode. I then make some changes and save it as .xlsm (FileFormat:=52), but it is still in compatability mode. Is there any way to turn off compatability mode without closing and re-opening the file?

```
If O_MSEx.Application.version < 12 Then ' older than Excel 2007
    FileFormatNum = -4143   ' .xls
Else
    FileFormatNum = 52  ' .xlsm
End If
Call O_MSEx.SaveAs(file_and_path, FileFormatNum)
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet of your code where you save the file?

Comment: Will do (won't give you any more info though).

Comment: What you have to do if it's originally an xls is save it as an xlsx then you can save it as an xlsm. First saving it as an xlsx converts it to the compatible version

Comment: I would expect that saving as xlsx will cause all the macros to be lost. That is why I am saving as xlsm. Even if this weren't an issue, I can't see why saving as xlsx rather than xlsm would make any difference. Did you try this?